# Add prefix/suffix to each member of an IEnumerable<string> in C#

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable, prefix

Is there an easy way to add a prefix or suffix to each member of an IEnumerable? I can't figure out a way besides (Where inputs is IEnumerable):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var str in inputs) {
    str = sb.Append(prefix).Append(str).ToString();
    sb.clear();
}
```

But this won't let me assign back to the str... And I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
var result = inputs
             .Select(x => prefix + x)
             .ToList();
```

It simply creates a new string for each *input* prepending the *prefix* and then put them into  a list.For *suffix* just change `prefix + x` to `x + suffix`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, I don't know why I didn't just see that, too long of a day...

Answer (score 2):

It worth to mention two wrong things with your code:

1. Your `str` variable is should be readonly inside foreach loop and you can't assign to it because strings are immutable and when you're calling `sb.Append(prefix).Append(str).ToString();` it creates a new string;
2. You don't need `StringBuilder` for this kind of task because it efficient when you do several concatenations to one string. In your case you have several strings each of which you need to concatenate with some variable only once.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so you can't just modify them whenever you want. You can return a **new** list though:

```
IEnumerable<String> AppendString (IEnumerable<String> src, String append)
{
   foreach (String str in src)
      yield return str + append;
}
```

Comment: You *can* add to them whenever you want. You just have to assign the result.

Comment: @SimonC, I thought it was clear that I meant "in-place" addition (that modifies the original string), so you needed to return a new list. I have edited to try and make this clearer, please let me know what you think. Sorry for the confusion.